# probit model - calculate standard error for mean ED50

Tags: r, statistics, regression, probability

I'm having trouble calculating an estimate of the standard error for the ED(LD) parameter in probit regression via the `glm()` function. The results I got don't contain the standard error for the current ED level (it's necessary to use Student's t-test for estimation of 2 different selection).

I use the following function (obtained from a journal article):

```
LD <- function(r, n, d, conf.level) {
    ## Set up a number series 
p <- seq(1, 99, 1)

## r=number responding, n=number treated, d=dose (untransformed), confidence interval level, 
    mod <- glm(cbind(r, (n-r)) ~ log10(d), family = binomial(link=probit))
    ### Calculate heterogeneity correction to confidence intervals according to Finney, 1971, (p.
### 72, eq. 4.27; also called "h")
    het = deviance(mod)/df.residual(mod)
    if(het < 1){het = 1} ### Heterogeneity cannot be less than 1

    ## Extract slope and intercept
    summary <- summary(mod, dispersion=het, cor = F)
    intercept <- summary$coefficients[1]
    interceptSE <- summary$coefficients[3]
    slope <- summary$coefficients[2]
    slopeSE <- summary$coefficients[4]
    z.value <- summary$coefficients[6]
    N <- sum(n)

    ## Intercept (alpha)
    b0<-intercept
    ## Slope (beta)
    b1<-slope
## Slope variance 
    vcov = summary(mod)$cov.unscaled
    var.b0<-vcov[1,1]
    ## Intercept variance
    var.b1<-vcov[2,2]
    ## Slope intercept covariance
    cov.b0.b1<-vcov[1,2]

    ## Adjust alpha depending on heterogeneity (Finney, 1971, p. 76)
    alpha<-1-conf.level
    if(het > 1) {talpha <- -qt(alpha/2, df=df.residual(mod))} else {talpha <- -qnorm(alpha/2)}

    ## Calculate g (Finney, 1971, p 78, eq. 4.36)  
## "With almost all good sets of data, g will be substantially smaller than 1.0 and 
## seldom greater than 0.4."
    g <- het * ((talpha^2 * var.b1)/b1^2)

## Calculate theta.hat for all LD levels based on probits in eta (Robertson et al., 2007, pg. 
## 27; or "m" in Finney, 1971, p. 78)
    eta = family(mod)$linkfun(p/100)  #probit distribution curve
    theta.hat <- (eta - b0)/b1

    ## Calculate correction of fiducial limits according to Fieller method (Finney, 1971, 
## p. 78-79. eq. 4.35) 
const1 <- (g/(1-g))*(theta.hat + cov.b0.b1/var.b1) # const1 <- (g/(1-g))*(theta.hat -   cov.b0.b1/var.b1)
const2a <- var.b0 + 2*cov.b0.b1*theta.hat + var.b1*theta.hat^2 - g*(var.b0 - (cov.b0.b1^2/var.b1))
    const2 <- talpha/((1-g)*b1) * sqrt(het * (const2a))

    ## Calculate the confidence intervals LCL=lower, UCL=upper (Finney, 1971, p. 78-79. eq. 4.35) 
    LCL <- (theta.hat + const1 - const2)
    UCL <- (theta.hat + const1 + const2)

    ## Calculate variance for theta.hat (Robertson et al., 2007, pg. 27)
    var.theta.hat <- (1/(theta.hat^2)) * ( var.b0 + 2*cov.b0.b1*theta.hat + var.b1*theta.hat^2 )

    ## Make a data frame from the data at all the different values
    ECtable <- data.frame(
      "p"=p,
      "N"=N,
      "EC"=10^theta.hat,
      "LCL"=10^LCL,
      "UCL"=10^UCL, 
      "slope"=slope, 
      "slopeSE"=slopeSE, 
      "intercept"=intercept, 
      "interceptSE"=interceptSE, 
      "z.value"=z.value, 
      "chisquare"=deviance(mod), 
      "df"=df.residual(mod), 
      "h"=het, 
      "g"=g,
      "theta.hat"=theta.hat,
      "var.theta.hat"=var.theta.hat)

    ## Select output level
    return(ECtable)
}
```

Example of usage:

```
result <- LD(data$effected, data$total, data$dose, 0.95)
```

In the result I get estimated ED-levels:

```
p   N   EC    LCL   UCL slope   slopeSE intercept   interceptSE z.value chisquare   df  h   g   theta.hat   var.theta.hat
49  49  24    39.26365  32.92103    41.18617    30.92579    12.21311    -49.32049   19.69812    2.532179    0.8584527   3   1   0.5991111   1.593991    0.06240212  0.3076671
50  50  24    39.33701  33.16216    41.26921    30.92579    12.21311    -49.32049   19.69812    2.532179    0.8584527   3   1   0.5991111   1.594801    0.06060359  0.3004097
51  51  24    39.41050  33.40318    41.35474    30.92579    12.21311    -49.32049   19.69812    2.532179    0.8584527   3   1   0.5991111   1.595612    0.05888568  0.2933069
```

But there is no estimated standard error for the current ED-level, nor degrees of freedom (df) for this standard error.
Does someone know how to calculate the standard error and df for current ED level? Can you help me modify this function to be more useful?

In many different books of math statistics and modeling calculation of std.error for ED level's are different:

- Finney's "Probit analysis" (third edition) suggests the following formula to aproximate the standard error: `Sm = 1/b*sqrt(Snw)`; `SE(LD50) = 10^m * log(e)10 * Sm`
- Finney has other more general formula: `V(m) = 1/b^2 * { 1/Snw + (m-x')^2/Snw(x-x')^2 }`
- The documentation for Stata and STATISTICA states the standard error for ED50 is aproximately `SEed50 = (ED84 - ED16) / sqrt(2N)`, where `N` is the total number of animals in the analyzed groups.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer the question of SE.
Instead it was a treasure for my question, I'd have asked.

## How to get the Probit estimate of concentration from glm probit model, similar to SPSS probit analysis; and confidence limits. [LLOD calculation using Probit analysis in R]

```
### Columns of data: response(r) = detected; number_obs(n) = total; dose(d) = conc
mdf = data.frame(conc=    c(50, 25,12.5,6.25,3.125, 1),
                 total=   c(10, 10, 10 ,  10,   10, 4),
                 detected=c(10, 10, 10 ,   8,    7, 0) )
#  model    (    r          n - r     )    ~  d
m3 =glm(cbind(detected, (total-detected))  ~ conc, family=binomial(link="probit"), data=mdf)
```

Instead of using derived data try using the raw data for true probit where reponses entered as binary 1 / 0  or T / F (the above one is "also works")

```
expand_probit_data <- function(mdf) {
  md_binary = mdf[0, c("conc", "detected")]
  for (x in 1:nrow(mdf)){
    n = mdf[x,"total"] ; r = mdf[x, "detected"] ; d= mdf[x, "conc"]
    md_binary <- rbind(md_binary, data.frame(conc=rep(d, n), detected = c(rep(1,r),rep(0,n-r))))
  }   # binary data can be T/F or TRUE/FALSE or 1 / 0 # but NOT character or levels e.g. "DET" / "NDET" 
  return (md_binary)
} # this will expand the short table to long binary form (somewhat reverse of : xtabs(~conc+detected, md_binary))    
md_binary <- expand_probit_data(mdf)
#  model     r  ~   d
m4 =glm(detected ~ conc, family=binomial(link="probit"), data=md_binary)
```

Now predict the probit values, concentrations at the p levels, and confidence limits. This is truly extracted from your code. Thank you for the thorough research and providing references.

```
get_estimate <- function (mod, p_level= c(0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 0.95, 0.99)) {
  ### Calculate heterogeneity correction to confidence intervals according to Finney, 1971, (p.72, eq. 4.27; also called "h")
  het = deviance(mod)/df.residual(mod) ; if(het < 1){het = 1} 
  # Heterogeneity cannot be less than 1 
  # R sets dispersion paramerter 1 by default #so I use 1, change if needed
  ## Extract slope and intercept 
  summary <- summary(mod, dispersion= 1, cor = F) # summary(mod, dispersion= het, cor = F)  # summary might change if het is lot > 1
  intercept <- summary$coefficients[1] ; interceptSE <- summary$coefficients[3]
  slope     <- summary$coefficients[2] ;     slopeSE <- summary$coefficients[4]
  z.value <- summary$coefficients[6]
  N <- sum(mdf$total) # or for m3 #  N <- nrow(md_binary) #this needs to be fixed: getting data from outside the supplied variables
  
  ## Intercept (alpha)  ## Slope (beta)
  b0 <- intercept   ;   b1 <- slope
  ## Slope variance  # Intercept variance  # Slope intercept covariance
  vcov = summary(mod)$cov.unscaled
  var.b0<-vcov[1,1] ;  var.b1<-vcov[2,2] ; cov.b0.b1<-vcov[1,2]
  
  ## Adjust alpha depending on heterogeneity (Finney, 1971, p. 76)
  alpha= 0.05  # fixed, otherwise # 1-conf.level  # e.g. if conf.level = 0.95
  if(het > 1) {talpha = -qt(alpha/2, df=df.residual(mod))} else {talpha = -qnorm(alpha/2)}
  
  ## Calculate g (Finney, 1971, p 78, eq. 4.36) ## "With almost all good sets of data, g will be substantially smaller than 1.0 and  seldom greater than 0.4."
  g <- het * ((talpha^2 * var.b1)/b1^2)
  
  ## Estimate   for all LD levels based on probits in eta ~~~~~~~~~~~| 
  ## (Robertson et al., 2007, pg.27; or "m" in Finney, 1971, p. 78)  |
  eta = family(mod)$linkfun(p_level)   #  probit distribution curve  |   p_levels = c(0.5, 0.9, 0.95, 0.99)
  eta_conc = (eta - b0)/b1  #  returns the conc or dose at p level   |   b0 = intercept ; b1 = slope
  ##----- this section was critical to my calculation _______________|  No way could I have got this estimate without this(@Mihail Pyatinskyi) post.
  # term theta.hat replaced by eta_conc here, for my convenience
  
  ## Calculate correction of fiducial limits according to Fieller method (Finney, 1971, p. 78-79. eq. 4.35) 
  const1 <- (g/(1-g))*(eta_conc + cov.b0.b1/var.b1) # const1 <- (g/(1-g))*(eta_conc -   cov.b0.b1/var.b1)
  const2a <- var.b0 + 2*cov.b0.b1*eta_conc + var.b1*eta_conc^2 - g*(var.b0 - (cov.b0.b1^2/var.b1))
  const2 <- talpha/((1-g)*b1) * sqrt(het * (const2a))
  
  ## Calculate the confidence intervals LCL=lower, UCL=upper (Finney, 1971, p. 78-79. eq. 4.35) 
  LCL <- (eta_conc + const1 - const2)
  UCL <- (eta_conc + const1 + const2)
  ##
  # Calculate variance (Robertson et al., 2007, pg. 27)
  var.eta_conc <- (1/(eta_conc^2)) * ( var.b0 + 2*cov.b0.b1*eta_conc + var.b1*eta_conc^2 )
  xtxt = cbind(p_level,conc_est=eta_conc, LCL=LCL, UCL=UCL, variance=var.eta_conc, sd.eta_conc=sqrt(var.eta_conc))
  return (xtxt)
}
```

The 0.5 is for EC50 or ED50 calculation, as yours (I guess )
People use EC90 (0.9) or LD10 (0.1) etc depending on context.
I am using specifically to calculate LLOD (lower limit of detection, for molecular detection assays) at probit 0.95. This script output matches very closely to the Probit calculation by SPSS.

```
p_level = c(0.5, 0.9, 0.95, 0.99)    # predict at these probability levels     
get_estimate(m3, p_level)
```

[image: Comparison of the two model's output to SPSS output]

Hope you figured out the SE yourself by now. You already had a variance calculation, I used sqrt of that to get Standard deviation. Worked on this example data.

Comment: Thanks for response, i spend a lot of time to improve this code and knowledge about probit assay's. Shortly: there is no reason to use std.error as feature to compare estimation of any p-levels. In probit assay should be used parallelism-test(Hypothesis of Parallelism) and equality-test (Hypothesis of Equality) to make comparison of different series of data.

Comment: I don't understand the two tests (Hypothesis of Parallelism and Equlity), but I didn't need them as yet. For many cases, when we are not comparing the probit values your this is enough to result the probit dose or concentration for LLOD at 95% probability or any other like EC50 or E90 or similar calculations. Plus this calculates the confidence limits. Great Job @MihailPyatinskyi, for your collection of knowledge on this, Thank you !

Comment: Yep, for estimate reason p-level & conf.limits is enough. But if you want investigate or compare results from different series of data parallelism and equality is required. I use probit for ichthyology purposes (determine on which length fish's reaches sexual maturation, 50% on p=0.5) and for comparison reason of 2(or more) diff. series parallelism required to make results statistically significant (to be sure, that series is obtained from one general population, as example - 2 different regression slope coef. leads to bias and fake conclusions).